# Is it possible to obtain fronto-parallel view of image or camera position by 2d-3d points relation?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

Is it possible to obtain front-parallel view of image or camera position by 2d-3d points relation using `OpenCV`?

For this I have intrinsic and extrinsic parameters. I have also 3d coordinates of set of control points (which lies in one plane) on image (relation 2d-3d).

In fact I need location and orientation of camera, but it is not difficult to find it if I can convert image to fronto-parallel view.

If it is not possible to do with OpenCV, are the other libraries which can solve this task?

Comment: By the way, is it good idea to write comments which are unrelated with question?

Comment: If you solved the problem but the specific answer isn't there, you should **add** the right answer yourself and accept it to let others know how to deal with that problem. That's the appropriate protocol.

Comment: ok, thanks, will keep in mind this in future (anyway I try to add my correct answers)

Comment: I don't think it's unrelated. Users with low AR have a hard time getting answers. By letting you know your AR is starting to get low and you can fix it, I'm preserving your integrity and **helping you get help from us**.

Comment: thanks. I fully agree with you, and track what you are speaking about, but it is not always easy to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is based on the formulas in the OpenCV documentation [Camera Calibration and 3D Reconstruction](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)

Let's consider numerical form without distortion coefficient (in contrast with matrix form).

We have `u` and `v`.
It is easy to calculate `x'` and `y'`.
But `x` and `y` can not be calculate because we can choose any non-zero `z`.
Line in 3d corresponds to one point in 2d image.

To solve this we take two points for `z=1` and `z=2`.
Then we find 2 points in 3d space which specify line `(x1,y1,z1)` and `(x2,y2,z2)`.

Then we can apply `R`<sup>-1</sup> to `(x1,y1,z1)` and `(x2,y2,z2)` which results in line determined by two points `(X1, Y1, Z1)` and `(X1, Y1, Z1)`.

Since our control points lie in one plane (let plane is Z=0 for simplicity) we can find corresponding `X` and `Y` point which is a point in 3d.

After applying normalization from `mm` to pixels we obtain fronto-parallel image.

(If we have input image distorted we should undistort it first)